Does the Lagrange Multipliers apply for this problem by ignoring some constraints?
Problem. Given four real numbers
$a_1 \ge a_2 \ge a_3 \ge a_4 > 0$
such that $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 = 9$
and $a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 + a_4^2 = 21$, find the minimum and maximum of $\frac{a_1}{a_4}$.
(Note: $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 = 9$
and $a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 + a_4^2 = 21$ along with $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4\ge 0$
ensure $a_i \ge 3/2, \forall i$. Thus, $\frac{a_1}{a_4}$ is bounded.)
Edit From @zetko's answer, I realize that we just ignore the boundary and find the points satisfying the Lagrange Multipliers equation system.
So I ask a bad question :).
By the way, this is a special case of this question.

Discussion.

Minimum

The minimum of $\frac{a_1}{a_4}$ is $\frac{14}{13} + \frac{3}{13}\sqrt{3}$ when
$$a_1 = a_2 = \frac94 + \frac14\sqrt{3}, \quad
a_3 = a_4 = \frac94 - \frac14\sqrt{3}. \tag{1}$$
We may ask can we apply the Lagrange Multipliers by ignoring the constraints $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge a_3 \ge a_4$? In other words, are there $\lambda$ and $\mu$ such that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a_i} = 0, \quad i = 1, 2, 3, 4? \tag{2}$$
where
$$f(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4) := \ln\frac{a_1}{a_4} - \lambda (a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 - 9) - \mu (a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 + a_4^2 - 21).$$
(Note: Take logarithm of the ratio
in order to simplify the calculations.)
The answer is No. If we plug the minimizer (1) into (2), there are no such $\lambda$ and $\mu$.
We should apply the KKT conditions instead. We have
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial a_i} = 0, \quad i = 1, 2, 3, 4 \tag{3}$$
where
\begin{align*}
 g(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4)
 &:= \ln\frac{a_1}{a_4} - \lambda (a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 - 9) - \mu (a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 + a_4^2 - 21)\\
 &\qquad  - r_1 (a_1 - a_2) - r_2(a_2 - a_3) - r_3(a_3 - a_4). 
\end{align*}
For example, for the minimizer (1), we have
$$\lambda = -\frac{28}{39}\sqrt{3},
\mu = \frac{2}{13}\sqrt{3},
r_1 = \frac{3}{13} - \frac{1}{39}\sqrt{3},
r_2 = 0, 
r_3 = \frac{3}{13} + \frac{1}{39}\sqrt{3}.$$
$\phantom{2}$

Maximum

The maximum is $\frac76 + \frac16\sqrt{13}$
when
$$a_1 = \frac{13}{6} + \frac16\sqrt{13}, 
\quad a_2 = a_3 = \frac73, \quad a_4 = \frac{13}{6} + \frac16\sqrt{13}. \tag{4}$$
Similarly, we may ask can we apply the Lagrange Multipliers by ignoring the constraints $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge a_3 \ge a_4$?
This time, there are $\lambda$ and $\mu$ along with the maximizer (4) such that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a_i} = 0, \quad i = 1, 2, 3, 4? \tag{5}$$
where
$$f(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4) := \ln\frac{a_1}{a_4} - \lambda (a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 - 9) - \mu (a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 + a_4^2 - 21).$$
$\phantom{2}$
Question. For an optimization problem, if we apply the Lagrange Multipliers by ignoring the constraints $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge a_3 \ge a_4$ and there are such $\lambda$ and $\mu$ and a feasible $(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4)$. Does it mean the KKT conditions is reduced to the Lagrange Multipliers?
In other words, does it mean the KKT conditions does not have another KKT point $\lambda$ and $\mu$ and a feasible $(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4)$?
Or, we should apply the KKT conditions rather than the Lagrange Multipliers. We need to check all the KKT points.

In general, if you ignore the constraint $a_1\geq a_2 \geq a_3 \geq a_4 > 0$ and apply Lagrange multipliers and find a global maximum/minimum(checking also the boundry), which additionaly satisfies your inequality constraint the anwser is optimal.
This is due to the fact that by imposing an additional constraint you search for a maximum/minimum over a subset. And $A \subset B \implies \max_Af(x) \leq \max_{B}f(x)$ and $\min_A f(x) \geq \min_Bf(x)$.

Thanks. This makes sense. For $n$ variables, the boundary $a_1\ge a_2 \ge \cdots \ge a_n > 0$ brings many cases to check? Does it make the Lagrange Multipliers impractical?

@RiverLi what does "Lagrange Multipliers impractical" mean? Essentially you're solving partial Lagrangian, and it happens that derived solution satisfies the ordering constraint, so it's optima.

@goldboy For the maximum, yes. For the minimum, do we need to check all the case in the boundary for general $n$? It seems too many cases. I posted a new question for the minimum. If you are interested in it and has a solution using the Lagrange Multipliers, you can go there https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4963071/seek-the-minimum-of-fraca-1a-n-if-a-1-ge-cdots-ge-a-n-0-and-sum.

In general, if we have $n$ positive variables $a_1, \dots, a_n$ and want to maximize $\frac{a_1}{a_n}$ subject to some symmetric constraints like these, then the condition $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge \dots \ge a_n$ is optional. Even without it:

$a_1$ will be the largest of any of the variables. (If some $a_i$ were larger, we could swap $a_1$ and $a_i$ and increase $\frac{a_1}{a_n}$ while still satisfying the constraints.)
Similarly, $a_n$ will be the smallest of any of the variables.
We might as well assume $a_2 \ge \dots \ge a_{n-1}$ since permuting these variables changes nothing.

So we know ahead of time that we can solve this problem by dropping the condition $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge a_3 \ge a_4$.

Thanks, you are right. For maximum, we can drop the constraint $a_1\ge a_2 \ge \cdots \ge a_n$. For minimum, we can not.

I think by symmetry, even for minimum problem, we can also drop the ordering constraint. No? @RiverLi

@goldboy I don't think so. If we drop the ordering constraint, the minimum will occur when $a_1 \le a_2 \le a_3 \le a_4$.

well, how about we do $min \frac{a_i}{a_j}$ for any $i\neq j$, and drop the ordering constraint?
