Seek the minimum of $\frac{a_1}{a_n}$ if $a_1 \ge \cdots \ge a_n > 0$ and $\sum_i a_i = b_1$ and $\sum_i a_i^2 = b_2$

Problem. Let $n\in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 3}$. Let $b_1, b_2$ be given real numbers such that $b_2 < b_1^2 < nb_2$. Let $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge \cdots \ge a_n > 0$ be real numbers such that $a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n = b_1$ and $a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \cdots + a_n^2 = b_2$. Find the minimum of $\frac{a_1}{a_n}$.

This is related to this question in which the maximum of $\frac{a_1}{a_n}$ is required. That question admits a nice solution.
After analyzing the minimizer for some examples, I guess the minimum of $a_1/a_n$ is given by
$$\beta := \min_{1\le k\le \lfloor b_1^2/b_2\rfloor} \frac{1 +  \sqrt{n/k - 1}\sqrt{nb_2/b_1^2 - 1}}{1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n/k - 1}}\sqrt{nb_2/b_1^2 - 1}}$$
which is achieved when $a_1 = \cdots = a_{k^\ast} > a_{k^\ast+1} = \cdots = a_n$ (here $k^\ast$ is minimizer of the above optimization problem).
If we can prove (by contradiction) that at minimum, $a_1 = \cdots = a_k > a_{k+1} = \cdots = a_n$ for some $k$,
then the problem is solved. I used this trick for some problems before, e.g. in my answer to this question.
However, I have not yet managed to tackle this problem.
An issue is that $\beta$ above is not in a closed form.
An example for $n = 4$ is given as follows (if someone wants to study the example to find some inspiration for the general case）.
Problem 1. Given four real numbers
$a_1 \ge a_2 \ge a_3 \ge a_4 > 0$
such that $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 = 9$
and $a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 + a_4^2 = 21$, find the minimum of $\frac{a_1}{a_4}$.
The minimum of $\frac{a_1}{a_4}$ is $\frac{14}{13} + \frac{3}{13}\sqrt{3}$ when
$$a_1 = a_2 = \frac94 + \frac14\sqrt{3}, \quad
a_3 = a_4 = \frac94 - \frac14\sqrt{3}.$$

my guess: if $n = 2k$, $a_1=\dots=a_{k}> a_{k+1}=\dots=a_n$; if $n=2k+1$, $a_1=\dots=a_k> a_{k+1}>a_{k+2}=\dots=a_n$

@goldboy I checked an example for $n=5$, $b_1 = 12, b_2 = 31$. The minimizer is $a_1 = a_2 > a_3 = a_4  = a_5$.

Is it possible the solution is not unique?

@goldboy For this example, we can prove that $a_1 = a_2 > a_3 > a_4 = a_5$ is surely not a minimizer.
